# How to interpret Nested Conditional Operator

Tags: c, code-snippets

i'm looking at part of an algorithm, and most of my c knowledge comes from knowing java. i understand that this is a conditional, but what exactly is the order of execution here/what's happening step by step? Thanks!

```
    int i, j, k;
    int *x = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        x[k] = j == n      ? a[i++]
             : i == m      ? a[j++]
             : a[j] < a[i] ? a[j++]
             :               a[i++];
    }
    free(x);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is equivalent to:

```
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (j == n) x[k] = a[i++];
        else if (i == m) x[k] = a[j++];
        else if (a[j] < a[i]) x[k] = a[j++];
        else x[k] = a[i++];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite this code to:

```
if (j == n)
    x[k] = a[i++];
else if (i == m)
    x[k] = a[j++];
else if (a[j] < a[i])
    x[k] = a[j++];
else
    x[k] = a[i++];
```

it looks like part of [merge sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: +1 for recognizing this as a merge.  I observe, however, that the merge is moot because the `x` is freed immediately after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

m and n are variables that have presumably been set beforehand and are non-negative integers, and x and a are arrays that (should have) been allocated.  In the case of a[] it presumably has some meaningful contents, and those contents, along with the values of m and n, will determine what x[] gets populated or updated with.

The purpose of the loop is completely opaque to me.  What it does:

Sets i to 0, j to m, and k to 0.
Looping from k == 0 to k == (n-1) inclusive

Sets x[k] to the following:

> - if j is n: a[i], then increments i
> - if j is not n:
>
>   > - if i is m:  a[j], then increments j
>   > - if i is not m:
>   >
>   >   > - if the value at a[j] is less than the value at a[i]: a[j], then increments j
>   >   > - if the value at a[i] is not less than the value at a[i]: a[i], then increments i

When the loop is complete, x[0] up to x[n-1] will have been populated with values from within a[], based on the contents of a, and the values of m and n.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are having trouble deciphering this code:

```
x[k] = j == n      ? a[i++]
     : i == m      ? a[j++]
     : a[j] < a[i] ? a[j++]
     :               a[i++];
```

Assuming so, this is the conditional operator, which -- as vsync demonstrates -- is very similar to an `if-else` statement. Essentially, this statement should be thought of as:

```
condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
```

This, it turns outs, is very similar but different from:

```
if (condition) 
    statementIfTrue;
else
    statementIfFalse;
```

The difference is that the *conditional operator always results in a value*, which might be assigned to a variable, otherwise used in an operation, passed as an argument, etc.... For the `if-then` statement to be equivalent, the two statement blocks would need to include the assignment.

Finally, there are multiple conditional operations nested, such that the `valueIfFalse` is resolved with another conditional operation.